# IE6/IE7 + Rounded corners...extra unwanted padding

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

Basically speaking, FF3 and IE8 render it this way, which is what I want:

[image: Firefox Render]

However, IE7 and IE8 render it like this:

[image: IE Render]

I use this solution for rounded corners without images:

http://www.editsite.net/blog/rounded_corners.html

And finally, here is my code and CSS (dynamically generated, so sorry for the lack of proper tabbing):

[HTML](http://www.yousendit.com/download/dVlxU2VrdGpCSnAzZUE9PQ)
[CSS](http://www.yousendit.com/download/dVlxU2VrdGpTRTVMWEE9PQ)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I too suffer from extra unwanted padding, but alas it has nothing to do with web browsers :'-(

Answer (score 2):

on the website you link to for the rounded corners js file, there are many comments that complain the script doesn't work in internet explorer. Since you are already including jquery, I can recommend a jQuery plugin called "corners" that seems to work in ie.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `corner-radius` CSS property and if someone is using an old browser then they just get no corners. This is a much better and scalable solution than bastardizing your page with unnecessary JavaScript that produces hundreds of excess divs - that's just plain silly!

Comment: Not so easy if you're building the site for someone and you have to tell them that about a third of their users won't get the rounded corner design. 

Although it is an idea to use the CSS for standards browsers and then include the js for ie using conditional comments.